# Lithium Ion Protection Circuit Model

Tags: battery-charging, ltspice, lithium-ion

I am trying to simulate the following Lithium Ion Battery Charger circuit in LTSPice:

[image]

I have looked online for the DW01A chip but can't find it. Can anyone please provide a model for this chip? If not, can anyone provide a protection circuit (overvoltage) that can be simulated in LTSpice? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to simulate it?

Comment: Try asking the manufacturer, maybe they made some official models.

Comment: @BruceAbbott If I could simulate this circuit in LTspice then I could try to modify it so that I have  12V at 5-10 Amps. This is for one or two cells

Comment: _"I could try to modify it so that I have 12V at 5-10 Amps. This is for one or two cells_ - the DW01A only does 1 cell. How will you get 12V out of one of two cells?